# Referencing an existing SignalR connection on the client side

Tags: c#, asp.net, azure, signalr

I'm having an issue with a project I'm doing at work with which I'm hoping someone here might be able to assist.

Without going into too much detail on the app itself, we have a location service which needs to use SignalR. The idea is that each client (when I say "client" what I mean is "person using the app") will be assigned to a particular "task", and send its GPS location to an Azure worker role every 2 (configurable) seconds, which will store the received data in two Azure tables. Then a second worker role will grab data from the tables and send a SignalR message to each client that's on a given task with the locations of all other clients assigned to the same task.

What I have currently is a test client (currently Winform, but it will be a UWP app) which can successfully use SignalR to send the location messages directly to the other clients, and I don't imagine it's going to be too difficult to slot in the Azure-side stuff, but my problem is with figuring out how to use SignalR groups to make sure messages only go to a particular task (I imagine the best way to do it is to name the groups with the IDs of the tasks) but when the hub connection is first established there isn't a task ID to name the group with, and the point in code where tasks are created doesn't have any direct access to the hub info. I'm probably missing something obvious but right now there doesn't seem to be any way for me to add a client to a group on the same hub connection it originally connected to at the point where a task is created.

**TL-DR: Is there a way for me to add clients to a SignalR group with a particular name, from a class in another project, on the hub it connected to when the app started?**

Answer (score 0):

1st Keep a UserId - ConnectionId association table somewhere.

2nd Upon Task Creation Create the signal R Group.

3rd Upon Task Assignment associate each user's connection to the signal R group.

Comment: How can I create the SignalR group/assign the connection to the group upon task assignment if the task creation/assignment class doesn't have a reference to the hub?

Comment: the task assignment should at least have a User Id  reference. so using this User Id  you will get the hub reference .

Comment: They do have a user ID reference, but I'm not sure how that relates to the SignalR hub as they're entirely separate. Sorry if I sound stupid, I've never worked with SignalR before.

Comment: public override Task OnConnected()
        {
            RTMServerFactory.GetServer().AddConnectionsToUser(Context.ConnectionId,Int32 UserId);
            return base.OnConnected();
        }

Where AddConnectionToUser is a storage method  to keep this association

Comment: Apparently RTMServerFactory doesn't exist. Tried Googling it but can't find any examples of it in code. Does it make a difference that currently my SignalR hub is in an ASP.NET web application contained in the solution?

Comment: RTMServerFactory Is just my personal wrapper to associate connections to users.

You should implement yours.

Comment: Understood, though that still doesn't help with the fact that I'm clueless as to how I can reference the hub when a task is created/asssigned. Maybe I just don't get the order of operations here.